# How to make field read-only after changing the field value

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com, apex

I have an object which has a field picklist it contains values **open** and **close** , what I am trying to achieve : when a record is inserted with the picklist value **close** I am trying to make the field read-only when the field changed to close.

How can I achieve this ???????

Answer (score 2):

You can add a validation rule like

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Field__c),ISPICKVAL(Field__c,"Close"))
```

That would throw an error if the field's value is "Close" and someone tries to change it.

Comment: Is it possible to do using workflows or triggers ? Because I am already using a workflow field update when the picklist value changed to close.

Comment: You could make a record type with a page layout that has that field as read-only, and then use a workflow field update to change the record type to the read-only one.  That seems overly heavy though.  The validation rule is the simplest way that achieves what you wrote there.

Answer (score 0):

Use two fields, where one is read-write and the other read-only.  The same information can be written to both fields using either a trigger or field-update rule.  Display the read-only when it's closed, else display the read-write field.

Of course, that's probably easier to do in Visualforce than not.